# Including files in assets into layout

Tags: php, html, layout, laravel-4, include-path

I have a basic install of Laravel 4.

I have set up layouts and templating using blade 4.

I have a logo and a css file in my assets directory.

```
/public/assets/img/logo.png
/public/assets/css/style.css
```

My layout is located:

```
/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php
```

What is the correct way to include these?

I have tried this for the logo for example:

But returns nothing. It also seems like laravel 4 and blade would have a more 'proper' way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `HTML helper` class.

for your CSS to appear in your `<head>` as a stylesheet link use:

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/style.css') }}
```

for your images use:

```
{{ HTML::image('assets/img/logo.png') }}
```

There are also `HTMLBuilder` methods for `.js` files and other things which are HTML-related.  Note that the URLs are relative to `/public` in your Laravel install.

For more information, you can consult the API docs at:

http://laravel.com/api/4.1/  I can't seem to link directly to a class, so navigate on the left to `Illuminate\Html\HtmlBuilder`